# Jquery: add iteration index to the name of the class of child/parent <divs> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page that has, 3 div with class name as "`xyz`", Now, On page load `($(document).ready(function())` for each occurance of the div "xyz" I want to introduce an inner html/child element as "`<div class="childxyz###"></div>`" where `###` represents the position number of the occurrence of parent class xyz . For instance, the first occurrence of parent class xyz the child class name would be "`childxyz1`", second occurrence it would be `childxyz2` and so on.

Can someone suggest a simple solution for this?

**Initial page**

```
<div class="xyz">
            //appending inner html and pass value 1 as xyz is the first occurrence
        </div> 

<div class="xyz">
    //appending inner html and pass value 2 as xyz is the first occurrence
</div> 

<div class="xyz">
    //appending inner html and pass value 3 as xyz is the first occurrence
</div>
```

**The final page when the Jquery/JS script runs should look like this.**

```
<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz1">
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz2">
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz3">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz1">
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz2">
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="xyz">
    <div class="childxyz3">
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I have included a sample code that I am working on, here I wish to replace the hard-coded value at the 0th and 1th position with a better code. Appreciate any help in this regard.

```
.datatableTesting0 thead tr th
.datatableTesting1 thead tr th
```

** What i want to achieve is a 2 Dimensional array that stores the values, such that, at the 0th position it store the content of first occurrence of class="datatableTesting" and at the 1th position the second occurrence of table with the same class name, so on and so forth.

```js
$(".datatableTesting").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("datatableTesting" + i);
});
var tableArray2 = new Array(10);
var tableArray1 = new Array(10);
$('.datatableTesting0 thead tr th').each(function(i) {
  var cellText = $(this).html();
  tableArray1.push(cellText);
});

$('.datatableTesting1 thead tr th').each(function(i) {
  var cellText = $(this).html();
  tableArray2.push(cellText);
});

$('.test1').each(function(i) {
  var cellText = $(this).html(tableArray1);

});

$('.test2').each(function(i) {
  var cellText = $(this).html(tableArray2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="datatableTesting" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="datatableTesting" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="test1" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
<table class="test2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? This is a very straightforward use of `$()` and `each` and `append` (and, if I'm reading the question right, the `%` operator). If you haven't already, spend an hour reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It really only takes that long, and it's *hugely* useful.

Comment: create a fiddle it  will be easy to fix

Comment: @gayathri: Snippet (on-site, the `<>` button), not fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");
for(var i=0;i<allNodes.length;i++){
    newNode = document.createElement("div");
    newNode.className = "childxyz" + (i+1);
    allNodes[i].appendChild(newNode);
}
```

this?

Comment: @yeppe: Or with jQuery: `$(".xyz").each(function(i) { $("<div>").addClass("childxyz" + i).appendTo(this); });`

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this (2D iteration.) for this custom requirement.

```
for (outerloop=0; outerloop < count; outerloop++){
        columns=0;
        var columns = $(".datatableTesting"+outerloop+" tr")[0].cells.length;
        tableCount[outerloop]=new Array(columns);
        $(".datatableTesting"+outerloop+" thead tr th").each(function(itrCol) {
            var cellText = $(this).html();  
            //fillvalue in the 2 Dimensional array 
            tableCount[outerloop][itrCol]=cellText;
        });
        createDOMStr[outerloop] //initialize to empty str.
        for (innerloop=0; innerloop < tableCount[outerloop].length; innerloop++){
            // append the string that you want to  display 
            createDOMStr[loopiter] = createDOMStr[loopiter] +//append the DOM string one row at at time.
        }

    }
```